# what to do in a situation when a class doesn’t implement a method from a protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c

what to do in a situation when a class doesn’t implement a method from a protocol

Comment: This is *far* too vague to effectively answer.

Comment: @user707139 - If we answer all your interview questions for you, does that mean one of us gets the job?

Comment: StackOverflow is a website targeted at **professional software developers**.  If you are not sure about what StackOverflow is or how to behave here, please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  Your question was closed because it is low quality and unanswerable in any reasonable manner.  If you wish to get good answers, you **must** ask good questions.  Low quality questions like this one are not accepted here.  I would **strongly** suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to invoke that method on objects of the class.

Obviously, unless the protocol declares the method as optional, you must implement the method in all classes that conform to the protocol.  That is the whole point of having the protocol at all.

However, if the method is optional, whenever you use it you must test the receiver to make sure it responds to the method.

e.g.

```
-(void) someMethod: (id<SomeProtocol>) foo
{
    if ([foo respondsTo: @selector(optionalMethodInSomeProtocol)])
    {
        [foo optionalMethodInSomeProtocol];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its an optional method you can leave it away, otherwise the class must implement all methods of the protocol. That's the rule.